# How do I transform existing log statements into interpolated string format?

Tags: string, scala, intellij-idea

I want to change existing statements such as

```
log.debug("Value of foo : {}", foo)
```

to use interpolated string format instead

```
log.debug(s"Value of foo : $foo")
```

Although IntelliJ has a [blog post](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2012/07/12/format-and-convert/) on converting between string formats, it seems to require having to first convert the existing string to

```
"Value of foo ".format(foo)
```

which defeats the purpose of wanting an automatic format change option in the first place (and doesn't work properly for me anyway).

How can I easily format these log statements to use string interpolation? Is there any way to do so wholesale (across an entire project)?

Comment: Note: Though I'm currently using IntelliJ, I'm open to any solution that works, whether its Eclipse, TextEdit, command line scripts etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IntelliJ, you can do `Inspect Code` (right click -> `Analyze` -> `Inspect Code`).  Make sure to turn on  `Legacy String Formatting` rule in your `Inspection Profile`.  I think this rule is part of the Scala plugin.

If you turn on this rule, you can make it a warning, error, or some other options.  You can always hit <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> while your cursor is on a statement with string concatenation and then select `convert to interpolated string` from the dropdown.

Comment: This should be a useful tip for strings using `.format`, but didn't help with log statements having comma-seperated arguments :(

Comment: This works for concatenated strings as well, not just strings with `format`

Comment: Accepting this as it answered my original (incorrectly worded) Q., and I haven't got a better answer for the actual issue.